# Google Sheets Script: Finding date from variable in a range

Tags: date, google-sheets, find, range

This is my first attempt at script. I'm pretty familiar with VBA. I have a date in A1 in the "Day" Sheet. I have a range of dates in column A on the "Monthly" sheet. I'm trying to find todays date on monthly sheet (from the variable on "Day" sheet) and paste the data there. I can't get past this first step of finding the date row. Basically the manager will have a form ("Day" Sheet) and when he hits the save button it will enter the data on the "Monthly" Sheet and it will clear the form. At the bottom I showed the execution log and it says -1.0 for the Index. Seems like it should say 2.0. Any help is much appreciated!

```
function moveValuesOnly () {

var ss          = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Day");
var reportSheet  = ss.getSheetByName("Monthly");
var todayDate = activeSheet.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();

var lookupRangeValues = reportSheet.getRange(2,1,32,1).getDisplayValues();

var index = lookupRangeValues.indexOf(todayDate);

/*
//cash on hand
activeSheet.getRange("I2").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("C" & index),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//POS Readout
activeSheet.getRange("B3").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("B" & index),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Waste or free pizza
activeSheet.getRange("B5").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("N" & index),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Dough made
activeSheet.getRange("B6").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("L" & index),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
//Total expenses itemized
activeSheet.getRange("A10:G15").copyTo(reportSheet.getRange("I" & index),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,false);
*/

Logger.log(todayDate);
Logger.log(lookupRangeValues);
Logger.log(index);

}
```

10:47:56 PM Notice  Execution started
10:47:57 PM Info    6/3
10:47:57 PM Info    [[6/1], [6/2], [6/3], [6/4], [6/5], [6/6], [6/7], [6/8], [6/9], [6/10], [6/11], [6/12], [6/13], [6/14], [6/15], [6/16], [6/17], [6/18], [6/19], [6/20], [6/21], [6/22], [6/23], [6/24], [6/25], [6/26], [6/27], [6/28], [6/29], [6/30], [], []]
10:47:57 PM Info    -1.0 //I believe this should be 2.0?
10:47:58 PM Notice  Execution completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-1.0` index means that the `todayDate` was not found on your `lookupRangeValues`. This is because lookupRangeValues is basically a 2d array and indexOf() is not applicable here. You should create a loop to find the index/row of `todayDate`. With this, you can replace your line of code with indexOf() to this loop:

```
for(var row in lookupRangeValues){
  if(lookupRangeValues[row][0]==todayDate){
    var index = row;
    break;
  }
}
```